# If $k + 1$ is prime and $(k + 1) \mid (q - 1)$, then $\sigma(q^k)$ is divisible by $k + 1$, but not by $(k + 1)^2$ (unless $k+1=2$).

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

I tried Googling for the keywords "the theory of odd perfect numbers" and one of the search results that came up was this [document](http://rcin.org.pl/Content/122677/WA35_145317_11371-4_Art60.pdf), titled *ON THE DIVISORS OF THE SUM OF A GEOMETRICAL SERIES WHOSE FIRST TERM IS UNITY AND COMMON RATIO ANY POSITIVE OR NEGATIVE INTEGER*.  (The author turns out to be J. J. Sylvester.)

Let me copy the first two paragraphs from that document:

> A REDUCED Fermatian, $\frac{r^p - 1}{r - 1}$, is obviously only another name for the sum of a geometrical series whose first term is unity and common ratio an integer, $r$.

> If $p$ is a prime number, it is easily seen that the above reduced Fermatian will not be divisible by $p$, unless $r - 1$ is so, in which case (unless $p$ is $2$) it will be divisible by $p$, but not by $p^2$.

Now, let me translate the second paragraph into modern language, fitted to the case of the divisor-sum function of the special prime power component of an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$, where $q$ is the special prime and satisfies $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  That is, we will be considering
$$\sigma(q^k) = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1},$$
where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical divisor sum function* of $x$.

(Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.)

Let us now see what we have got.  Translating to modern language (in the context of $\sigma(q^k)$):

> **PROPOSITION:** If $k + 1$ is prime and $(k + 1) \mid (q - 1)$, then $\sigma(q^k)$ is divisible by $k + 1$, but not by $(k + 1)^2$ **(unless $k+1=2$)**.

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** What happens to the **PROPOSITION** when $k=1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture holds.  Then $k=1$.

Then $k+1=2$ is prime.  Also, since $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, so that $2 = (k + 1) \mid (q - 1)$.  Then $\sigma(q^k)$ is divisible by $(k+1)=2$ but not by $(k+1)^2=4$, which is true.  So what's with the **UNLESS**?

Here is a proof for $\sigma(q^k) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$:

> > First, since $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
> > $$\sigma(q^k) = 1 + q + \ldots + q^k \equiv k + 1 \pmod 4.$$
> > Next, since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
> > $$\sigma(q^k) \equiv k + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$$
> > **QED**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is deduced due to a famous lemma often called as "LTE lemma" (Lifting the exponents). The lemma is as follows:

> If $p\not=2$ is a prime number and $a,b$ are positive integers such that $p|a-b$, then for every positive integer $n$ we have : $V_p(a^n-b^n)=V_p(a-b)+V_p(n)$

The lemma also holds for $p=2$ but it's slightly different in that case. This theorem can be easily proved using induction.
Anyways using LTE lemma on your problem, since $p=k+1|q-1$, then $$V_p(\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1})=V_p(q^{k+1}-1)-V_p(q-1)=V_p(q-1)+V_p(k+1)-V_p(q-1)=V_p(k+1)$$
But we know that $V_p(k+1)=V_p(p)=1$ so finally $V_p(\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1})=1$ hence the sum of divisors is divisible by $p$ but not by $p^2$.

P.S. Here is almost everything on the lemma
[image: P.S. Here is almost everything on the lemma]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Aryaaaaan!  Mind sharing more details for the lemma under the case $p=2$ (which is, essentially, what I am interested in)?

Comment: I'll add my notes on it in the answer

Comment: Theorem I is indeed super-useful.  In my case, since
$$(q - 1)\sigma(q^k) = q^{k+1} - 1,$$
then supposing to the contrary that
$$5^k + 1 \leq q^k + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k) = k + 1  \implies 5^k \leq k,$$
which contradicts $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  (That is, no solutions exist for the inequality $5^k \leq k$.)

Comment: That is, the hypothesis
$$(q - 1)\sigma(q^k) = q^{k+1} - 1 \neq k + 1$$
of Theorem I is satisfied (for the divisor sum of the special prime power component of an odd perfect number that I am considering), and thus the conclusion "$q^{k+1} - 1$ has a prime divisor that does not divide $q - 1$" holds.

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @Aryaaaaan!  =)

Comment: It is actually a weaker version of the famous Zsigmondi theorem which is super powerful :)